# Easiest Way To Return A Boolean Value For A Searched Key/Value Pair (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON string...

**JSON:**

[{"my_id":"100002","my_confirmation":"682354682"},{"my_id":"100005","my_confirmation":"281735345"},{"my_id":"100009","my_confirmation":"361567356"}]

... which I have then parsed into a key/value pair array.

What is the easiest way to return, via Javascript, a boolean value if attempting to match "my_id" for "100005"? And also, is the parsing into an array necessary?

Comment: You might be able to just do `str.indexOf('"my_id":"100005"') > -1` if you don't want to parse the JSON. It don't really see it's purpose though. Don't you want to do something with the data anyway?

Comment: Could do a regex match as well. there are lots of ways to do this .  What did you investigate ?

Comment: @FelixKling Its just a minor function which I'll be calling occasionally just to flag items for CSS class elements.

Answer (score 3):

If you are already parsing the JSON string then in ECMA5 you could use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Javascript

```
var jsonString = '[{"my_id":"100002","my_confirmation":"682354682"},{"my_id":"100005","my_confirmation":"281735345"},{"my_id":"100009","my_confirmation":"361567356"}]';

var matches = JSON.parse(jsonString).some(function (obj) {
    return obj.my_id === '100005';
});

console.log(matches);
```

Output

```
true
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/kGfyy/)

or you could go even more funky like this

```
function myContains(jsonStr, key, value) {
    return JSON.parse(jsonStr).some(function (obj) {
        return obj[key] === value;
    });
}

var jsonString = '[{"my_id":"100002","my_confirmation":"682354682"},{"my_id":"100005","my_confirmation":"281735345"},{"my_id":"100009","my_confirmation":"361567356"}]';

console.log(myContains(jsonString, 'my_id', '100005'));
```